# SwiftUI - Dynamically hiding and displaying a tabbar is causing an issue when displaying a dynamic list of items in a NavigationView

Tags: firebase, swiftui, tabbar, navigationview

Here is the main ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var displayDetails: DisplayDetails

    @State var selected = 0

    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
        
        ContactList()
        
        Spacer()
        
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            
            if (!displayDetails.showFullScreen) {
                
                BottomBar(selected: self.$selected)
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.horizontal, 22)
                    .background(CurvedShape())
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    
                    Image("Wishlist")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .padding(18)
                    
                }
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .offset(y: -32)
                .shadow(radius: 5)
                
            }
            
        }
        
        }
        .background(Color("Color").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))

    }

}

struct CurvedShape : View {

    var body : some View {
    
    Path { path in
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 55))
        
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: 55), radius: 30, startAngle: .zero, endAngle: .init(degrees: 180), clockwise: true)
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 55))
        
    }
    .fill(Color.white)
    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 180))

    }

}

struct BottomBar : View {

    @Binding var selected : Int

    var body : some View{
    
    HStack{
        
        Button(action: {
            
            self.selected = 0
            
        }) {
            
            Image("home")
            
        }
        .foregroundColor(self.selected == 0 ? .black : .gray)
        
        Spacer(minLength: 12)
        
        Button(action: {
            
            self.selected = 1
            
        }) {
            
            Image("search")
            
        }
        .foregroundColor(self.selected == 1 ? .black : .gray)
        
        Spacer().frame(width: 120)
        
        Button(action: {
            
            self.selected = 2
            
        }) {
            
            Image("person")
            
        }
        .foregroundColor(self.selected == 2 ? .black : .gray)
        .offset(x: -10)

        Spacer(minLength: 12)
        
        Button(action: {
            
            self.selected = 3
            
        }) {
            
            Image("menu")
            
        }
        .foregroundColor(self.selected == 3 ? .black : .gray)
        
    }
    
    }

}
```

This is the Detailed View:

```
struct DetailView: View {

    let contact: Contact

    @EnvironmentObject var displayDetails: DisplayDetails

    var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
    
        Image(contact.imageName)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .clipped()
            .cornerRadius(150)
            .shadow(radius: 3)
        
        Text(contact.name)
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.medium)
        
        Form {
        
            Section {
            
                HStack {
                
                    Text("Phone")
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text(contact.phone)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.callout)
                
                }
                
                HStack {
                
                    Text("Email")
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text(contact.email)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.callout)
                
                }
                
                HStack {
                
                    Text("Address")
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text(contact.address)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.callout)
                        .frame(width: 180)
                
                }
            
            }
            
            Section {
            
                Button(action: {
                
                    print("Send a message")
                
                }) {
                    
                    Text("Send a message")
                
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                
                    print("Call")
                
                }) {
                
                    Text("Call")
                
                }
            
            }
        
        }
    
    }
    .onDisappear() {
        
        self.displayDetails.showFullScreen.toggle()
    
    }
    .onAppear(){
    
        self.displayDetails.showFullScreen.toggle()
    
    }
    .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
        
    }

}
```

This is NavigationView List (ContactList):

```
struct ContactList: View {

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ContactViewModel()

    var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
    
        List(viewModel.contacts) { contact in
            
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(contact: contact)) {
            
                ContactRow(contact: contact)
            
            }
        
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Contacts")
        .onAppear(){
            
            self.viewModel.fetchdata()
            
        }
    
    }
    .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)

    }

}



struct ContactRow: View {

    let contact: Contact

    var body: some View {
    
    HStack {

        Image(contact.imageName)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
            .clipped()
            .cornerRadius(50)

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            Text(contact.name)
                .font(.system(size: 21, weight: .medium, design: .default))

            Text(contact.phone)

        }

    }

    }

}
```

and lastly the ObservableObject that toggles based on tabbar needing to be hidden or visable:

```
class DisplayDetails: ObservableObject {

    // Used to move to full screen when detail view is displayed in application
    @Published var showFullScreen: Bool = false

}
```

All that you need to do is setup Firebase Firestore (or other source) to be the dynamic data for the NavigationView (List)

Here is a easy tutorial to follow to do so for Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

(you will need to create the Firestore instance in GCP and d/l the json file and add to the project)

I can NOT get the navigation to work as desired as the NavigationView will not work correctly!? I am not sure if it is a Firebase issue or SwiftUI issue!? Most likely SwiftUI.

As you can see, on the navigation back to the List of items, the list itself rolls back up into the first item and disappears?

** ISSUE ** in the instance you did not d/l the sample project I created for you to view the behavior yourself:

When user click on an item in the list it navigates to the detailed view and hides the tab bar as desired. **When the transition starts the navigation transition to the detailed view the list view rolls up the items in the list (which is weird)?? I expected just a slide to the detailed view (which happens when the list of items is static, like in a hard coded array). When user click the back button to return the list; the list is displayed (its like its unrolling from the first item in the list) and then the list rolls back up again into the first item and the screen ends up blank!?

Has anyone encountered this issue and have you been able to resolve it!?

Comment: Please add a [example] in your question.

Comment: @koen code added in question, also I added the exact code in the first link to test it out yourself if wanted.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Your title mentions a problem with hiding/showing a tab bar, but then in the question you say the NavigationView will not work correctly.

Comment: @koen When user click on an item in the list it navigates to the detailed view and hides the tab bar as desired. **When the transition starts the navigation transition to the detailed view the list view rolls up the items in the list (which is weird)?? I expected just a slide to the detailed view (which happens when the list of items is static, like in a hard coded array). When user click the back button to return the list; the list is displayed (its like its unrolling from the first item in the list) and then the list rolls back up again into the first item and the screen ends up blank!?

Comment: @koen were you able to reproduce!?

Comment: Haven't looked at it. I don't have a Firebase account (and am not going to sign up) - so is your sample code in the question a [example] that works without Firebase?

Comment: @koen, it is a minimal reproducible example which should work regardless , just make the data source from somewhere dynamic and not static or hard coded in an array. My code has the static array , and if you use that as the source you will see it work as expected. Remove the static data source and use dynamic and see it break.

Comment: So you only see the error when the source is dynamic? Then maybe it's an async issue and you are updating the UI while the download is still processing. I would look into that. Like I said, I don't know Firebase, so cannot help you debug that part of your code.

Comment: @koen thanks for the insight. I was hoping someone in the Google Firebase team and/or any other firebase resources developers could potentially jump in to assist.